# aadb2c90243: the idps client key/secret is not properly configured

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am getting the error,"aadb2c90243: the idps client key/secret is not properly configured" on android application that I have setup for authentication with Azure ADB2C. The error occurs when I press on the Microsoft social login that is amongst my social logins in the specified user flow. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

•   Please check whether your OAuth redirect URIs are correct or not, also, they should not be expired or invalid, i.e., they should be ‘ https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp ’ or ‘ https://your-domain-name/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp ’. There should be no trace of ‘login.microsoftonline.com’ in the redirect URIs in the android version of the app configured for logging into the Microsoft personal accounts.

•   Please check the ‘APP ID’ and the corresponding ‘App secret’ created for logging into the Microsoft social accounts through your app page. As it may be conflicting to login with the Microsoft social personal accounts using the Azure AD B2C authentication. Thus, would suggest you to please check the redirect URIs for the app configured in Azure AD B2C authentication user flow.

Please refer the below link for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Hi, looking at your answer it seems your solution is based on AppAuth library. If so, is AppAuth library the only option to make this work for this work for Azure ADB2C?

Comment: No, but the description of the problem which you stated above mostly points to the AppAuth library and configuration of App user flows in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: My application does not use the AppAuth library. This is why I don't understand the connection with the error message as I have not setup a key and secret combination in the mobile app. In my mobile app log there is a correlation ID generated with the error message. Will it help with the investigation if I shared it?

Comment: Yes, please share it as well as please check the above stated requirements in Azure also as you have setup your app authentication there.

Comment: Yes, I had confirmed the redirects are in place and app authentication as per your recommendation. Below are the error details along with the correlation id. server_error;AADB2C90243: The IDP's client key/secret is not properly configured.
Correlation ID: 7b40d5c8-891f-4c10-8238-8662245d256a
Timestamp: 2021-11-08 18:50:45Z

Comment: Please try resetting the IDP's client key/secret and using the newly created ones. May be that would help resolve them.

Comment: No, I didn't solve it as the error message has no correlation with my setup. I opted to use a different authentication and authorization logic for my application